# Node js TypeScript: Good way to copy one file content from File object to another File object

Tags: node.js, typescript, file-copying

I am in Node version 16.5.0 with TypeScript.

### Problem Statement

I have a two File Objects - src and destination(`Note`: not file paths of type string, but file object of type `File`).
I want to optimally (best way) to copy the src content to destination content. I can use, if needed streaming also.

### Tried so far

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import { isUndefined } from 'lodash';
import path from 'path';

export class FileUtil {
    public saveLogFile(parentDir: File, instanceId: string, content: File) {
        const srcFilePath: string = `${parentDir}/instance_${instanceId}_mediatorLog.tgz`;
        const destFilePath: string = `${parentDir}/${content.name}`;
        const srcFileWithAbsolutePath = path.resolve(srcFilePath);
        const destFileAbsolutePath = path.resolve(destFilePath);
        fs.stat(srcFilePath, function(err) {
            if (isUndefined(err)) {
                fs.copyFile(srcFileWithAbsolutePath, destFileAbsolutePath, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The solution is glitchy so far. I also don't think it's pretty optimized (though did not yet bench marked yet).

Reaching out to experts if there is a better way in NodeJS+TS world to do it.

Comment: I've never seen [`isUndefined`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L12198) used before

Comment: Its lodash. Just can be assumed as null check. Not too much important. We can just make it like if (!err) also. No issue.

Comment: How is the solution glitchy? What does it mean?

Comment: It means it's not optimized or there can be failures too.
So a better steaming solution, if possible.
Better: Better in performance or resiliency.

Comment: What's file size?

Comment: Would it be okay if both files were always same (i.e. when one is edited another also gets edited the same way)?

Comment: File size some MBs (10th of mb order)

Comment: Actually the usecase is log copying and zipping for archive. So one needs to be copied into another.cant be edited same time.